# coffeescript is always returning the response object

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript

i've the following codes in coffeescript

```
getSection = (url) ->
  req = $.getJSON url
  return req.success (data) ->
    data.section
```

or,

```
getSection = (url) ->
  req = $.getJSON url
  req.success (data) ->
    data.section
```

i intended to return `data.section` for the function `getSection`. but it is always returning another object (probably the response/ajax object). how can I force to return the values in data.section from this inner function?

thanks in advance?

Comment: Do you want to return from getSection, or from the success callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) is an AJAX call and **A** stands for **asynchronous** so `getSection` will return before `$.getJSON` gets its response back from the server. Basically, you can't get `getSection` to return `data.section` unless you want to replace `$.getJSON` with [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and do a synchronous (i.e. non-asynchronous) call; however, synchronous calls are evil and are being deprecated so you shouldn't use them.

The usual solution is to pass a callback to `getSection`:

```
getSection = (url, callback) ->
  req = $.getJSON url
  req.success (data) ->
    callback(data.section)
```

and then you put your logic in `callback` rather than trying to do something with the `getSection` return value.

Your `getSection` is returning `req` because that's what [`req.success`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) returns and CoffeeScript functions return their final value.

Comment: thanks for your response! I really forgot that getSection will return before getJSON is completed! as I now know the reason, I will make some work around.

Comment: yes, i've written a function that will do the job after the data is loaded from getJSON and called that function from success callback, much like the way you've shown :). thanks