# Rails - Improve handling json response with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a synchronous script for page preview. `preview` function simply sends data to server, `hookPreview` fires it on a click, and it's supposed to append response data on success.

```
window.Wiki = 
    preview: (raw_data) ->
        preview_path = "/wiki/preview"

        $.post preview_path,
            "raw_data": raw_data,
            (data) ->
                $("#preview").html data.raw_data
            "json"

    hookPreview: (tab, textarea) ->
        # Send data to controller on click
        $(tab).bind "click", ->
            res = Wiki.preview $(textarea).val()
            console.log(res)
            true

$(document).ready ->
    Wiki.hookPreview($("#preview-tab"), $(".editor"))
```

I can inspect response `res` in console: `Object {readyState: 1}` with callback functions, but I couldn't call `res.status` (which is 200 in my console) where gives me "undefined".

First, how to parse the response? Second, I want to improve my script to asynchronous style (as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11791167/4031374)).

**Edit**:

In controller:

```
def preview
  # ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json
  end
end
```

which uses `preview.json.erb`:

```
<%= {:body => @preview }.to_json.html_safe %>
```

Logger in terminal showed server completed with "200 OK" thus the problem is with script, not on server side.

Comment: use `JSON.parse` method

Comment: @uzaif `data = $.parseJSON(res)` throws unexpected token error.

Comment: do you have any console error?

Comment: No error, except I couldn't fetch attributes of the response object.

Comment: did you check res value in controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109026/discussion-between-uzaif-and-knh170).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.post` like all the ajax methods returns a promise object - not the actual response.

Promise objects are like a token which at some point in time will contain the response.

To inspect the response you would need to add a `.done` callback to the promise:

```
window.Wiki = 
    preview: (raw_data) ->
        preview_path = "/wiki/preview"

        $.post preview_path,
            "raw_data": raw_data,
            (data) ->
                $("#preview").html data.raw_data
            "json"

    hookPreview: (tab, textarea) ->
        # Send data to controller on click
        # jQuery.bind is depreciated - use .on instead
        $(tab).on "click", ->
            promise = Wiki.preview( $(textarea).val() )
            promise.done (data) ->
              console.log(data) 
            true

$(document).ready ->
    Wiki.hookPreview($("#preview-tab"), $(".editor"))
```